# Can't read a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

In the console, I can't seem to log the values, "male" or "female". It should be something like, `console.log(choice[0].a)`. It is not logging the value of the variable `string`. Below is what I have tried, thank you for your time.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var string = "";
            var randoml = "ab";
            while (string.length < 1) {
              string += randoml[Math.floor(Math.random() * randoml.length)];
            } 
            console.log(string);
           data = '[{"a" : "male", "b" : "female"}]';
           var choice = JSON.parse(data);
           console.log(choice[0].string); 
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you create a string just to JSON.parse it? Simply creating the object would be much easier

Answer (score 6):

```
console.log(choice[0][string]);
```

Theres no string property in your object, but rather a value related to the key, that string contains.

A bit shorter:

```
console.log(Math.round(Math.random())?"male":"female");
```

Comment: Missed by seconds! Nice +!

Comment: `Math.round(Math.random())` is even shorter ;)

Comment: @phil but that wouldnt be equaly distributed ?

Comment: `[0, 0.5)` would be `0`, `[0.5, 1)` would be `1`. Seems even (unless I'm missing something obvious)